# How to share a picture and description with a specific person with an ID in Telegram with Android?

Tags: java, android

I need to share image and Description to specific person in telegram.
by below code, i do to specific person in telegram to write manual text.

```
Intent telegram = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
telegram.setData(Uri.parse("https://telegram.me/person id"));
telegram.setPackage("org.telegram.messenger");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(telegram, ""));
```

Hello.
I have to share the picture and description with a special person in Telegram.
With the following code, I can enter the chat page with a specific person in Telegram and type and send the text manually.
But I want to Choose the photo and text in the app and when I enter the chat page, just i click the send button..

Answer (score 0):

you try this code:

```
String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.setPackage("org.telegram.messenger");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "");
```